# Rsync dns issue

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync

Recently the backup script I've been using for years has started to give me trouble. The part that's problematic boils down to this:

```sh
for DIR in "${BACKUP_DIRS[@]}"; do
    rsync --acls --archive --delete \
        --link-dest=${DIR} \
        --stats \
        --verbose \
        --rsh="ssh -o BatchMode=yes -i ${KEY}" \
        "${USER}"@${HOST}:"${DIR}" "${BACKUP_DIR}/"
done
```

Now the problem I have is that on the first (and only the first) directory listed in `${BACKUP_DIRS[@]}`, `rsync` exits with an error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname <host>: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.3]
An error occurred during backup of <dir>.
```

Any clues on how to resolve this are very much appreciated.

Comment: Well, can you resolve the host?

Comment: Yeah, I can. Like I said, only the first directory in the list of locations I want to back up fails (there are multiple for a single server).

Comment: Sounds like the recursive resolver is taking too long to resolve the host; `rsync` times out, but on the 2nd attempt, the resolver already has the `A` record cached.

Does it help if you add a `for i in 1 2 3; do ping -c1 $HOST; done` above your existing `for` loop?

Comment: That may very well be the case indeed. I added a line `getent ahosts ${HOST} &>/dev/null` which appears to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by András Korn, the problem was that the DNS resolver takes too long.

By adding and extra DNS lookup before invoking `rsync`, the query result will be fast when `rsync` is called, since the query result has been cached.

DNS lookup can be forced using `getent`, `host`, `dig` or by pinging the host.